# Multiple APEX_PUBLIC_USER sessions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, apex, oracle-apex-5.1

[image: 1]

I have an ORACLE database and ORACLE APEX 5.1 is installed there.
It has worked well in previous days.
In recent days, the server has crashed due to many sessions generated by the user APEX_PUBLIC_USER.

Seeing the current statement, this:

```
/* Formatted on 30/12/2022 05:19:20 p. m. (QP5 v5.336) */
DECLARE
    rc__             NUMBER;
    simple_list__    OWA_UTIL.vc_arr;
    complex_list__   OWA_UTIL.vc_arr;
BEGIN
    OWA.init_cgi_env ( :n__, :nm__, :v__);
    HTP.HTBUF_LEN := 63;
    NULL;
    NULL;
    simple_list__ (1) := 'sys.%';
    simple_list__ (2) := 'dbms\_%';
    simple_list__ (3) := 'utl\_%';
    simple_list__ (4) := 'owa\_%';
    simple_list__ (5) := 'owa.%';
    simple_list__ (6) := 'htp.%';
    simple_list__ (7) := 'htf.%';
    simple_list__ (8) := 'wpg_docload.%';
    simple_list__ (9) := 'ctxsys.%';
    simple_list__ (10) := 'mdsys.%';

    IF (   (wwv_flow_epg_include_modules.authorize ('wwv_flow.ajax') = FALSE)
        OR (owa_match.match_pattern (p_string              => 'wwv_flow.ajax'/* */
                                                                             ,
                                     p_simple_pattern      => simple_list__,
                                     p_complex_pattern     => complex_list__,
                                     p_use_special_chars   => FALSE)))
    THEN
        rc__ := 2;
    ELSE
        NULL;
        NULL;
        wwv_flow.ajax (p_flow_id        => :p_flow_id,
                       p_flow_step_id   => :p_flow_step_id,
                       p_instance       => :p_instance,
                       p_debug          => :p_debug,
                       p_request        => :p_request,
                       p_json           => :p_json);

        IF (WPG_DOCLOAD.is_file_download)
        THEN
            rc__ := 1;
            WPG_DOCLOAD.get_download_file ( :doc_info);
            NULL;
            NULL;
            NULL;
            COMMIT;
        ELSE
            rc__ := 0;
            NULL;
            NULL;
            NULL;
            COMMIT;
            OWA.get_page ( :data__, :ndata__);
        END IF;
    END IF;

    :rc__ := rc__;
END;
```

I delete the sessions and they are recreated.

What solution could it be?
Migrate from DB?
New version of APEX?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541). Put the table _after_ your description of the problem.

Comment: How do you know that is what crashed your server? What errors or warnings were in the DB alert logs or system logs?